# Java unicode operations

Tags: java, unicode

I'm doing a project in network security using java. I need to deal with the unicode values directly. But i couldn't find any material to study about the unicode operations. Is there any separate class to manipulate the unicode values directly?
Could anyone help with the unicode operations???

Comment: Can you be more specific? Which unicode operations? A Java `char` represents a unicode code point, and `String`s are unicode strings.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by "manipulate the Unicode values directly"?  The `char` datatype is built in and natively represents Unicode characters (or UTF-16 surrogates, if you're dealing with values outside the Basic Multilingual Plane).

Comment: You are right. But i couldn't perform the read and write operations on all unicode values. Is there any method to read and write all unicode values?

Answer (score 1):

You can using Apache Commons Lang3, see : [**http://commons.apache.org/lang/**](http://commons.apache.org/lang/)
In this utility you can find useful utility classes. A useful class is CharUtils, this class has operations for working with char and unicode. Following snippet code show a sample for your situation:

```
System.out.println(CharUtils.unicodeEscaped(' '));
System.out.println(CharUtils.unicodeEscaped('A'));
```

output will:

```
\u0020
\u0041
```

java doc of unicodeEscaped method says: **"Converts the string to the Unicode format"**.
In this library exist more usefull utility, for example utility for Boolean, String, Enumeration, Serialization and more.